# How to know whether the app is running under emulator or physical device?

Tags: android

I'm trying to solve an issue for build my app. I want to prevent my app from running under any emulator like Bluestacks, Genymotion, and Nox.

How can I do this using code?

Comment: Welcoe evassmhi. Please read [how to ask] (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and proof read before posting... like fix the device typo in your heading

Answer (score 1):

You can't get directly. But the trick is available. Like by getting the SIM details (whether SIM is available or not). Because only real devices have SIM facility.

Comment: Hi suresh but some tablets dont hav the sim facility right how can I consider those cases ?

Comment: Yes i accept you. But the best way is checking sim details. Other then that the difference between emulator and real device  is bluetooth and wifi. These two won't work properly in emulators. But i always suggest you to sim functionality.